# Can someone find the error in my php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking for a mistake in my php and mysql for the past 5 hours. I have no clue what I have done wrong or if there is just a problem with my mamp. I think it may be a problem with my mamp. This is where I believe the problem would be taking place. But the problem is that now every page comes up blank. Thanks.

**site/core/init.php**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
     error_reporting(0);

     require 'database/connect.php';
     require 'database/general.php';
      require 'functions/users.php';

      $errors = array();
    ?>
```

**site/core/functions/users.php**

```
    <?php
    function user_exists($username) {
        $username = sanitize($username);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
        return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1 ) ? true : false;
    }
    ?>
```

**site/includes/widgets/logins**

```
        <aside>         
            <div class = "rightsidebar">
                <h2>Log in/Register</h2>
                <form action = "login.php" method = "post">
                    <ul id = ".login">
                        <li>
                            Username:<br>
                            <input type = "text" name = "username">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Password:<br>
                            <input type = "password" name = "password">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type = "submit" value = "Log In">
                        </li>                                                       
                        <li>
                            <a href = "register.php"><p>Register</p></a>
                        </li>                       
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

**site/core/database/connect.php**

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('lr');
    ?>
```

**site/core/functions/general.php**

```
    <?php
        function sanitize($data) {
            return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        }

    ?>
```

**site/login.php**

```
    <?php
    include 'core/init.php';

    if (user_exists('ben') === true) {
        echo 'exists';
    }
    die();

    if(empty($_POST) === false) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username) === true | | empty($password) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
        } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'We ca\'nt find that username. Have you registered?';
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you consider removing the call to `error_reporting(0);` to see if it tells you what's wrong?

Comment: Did you consider not calling `die()` unconditionally in login.php?

Comment: Why using quote(') for table name and field name, you can use (`) instead (').

Comment: Even *no* quotes for the table names would be better than single-quotes.  BTW, `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: The problem is obviously the spelling error: `ca\'nt` (in `login.php`).

Answer (score 0):

In query table name and column name should not be wrapped with `'` (quot). Either you can use `` ` `` or nothing.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly track your errors starting from the first included file`require 'database/connect.php';` .
Try `or die(mysql_error());` after connection , selecting your db and your query.
Try to use `echo 'a'; echo 'b'; echo 'c';` in the rest of files to catch where is the `die` or `error` exactly occurs.
Try to echo your `$_POST` data to check if it comes true.
Try to check your `network panel` in your browser to catch the request that made that error.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in login.php. No space allowed between OR operator syntax.

```
if(empty($username) === true | | empty($password) === true) {
```

Should be

```
if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
```

Comment: @OP: Note, this would have been clear as day if you hadn't decided to turn error reporting off.